# Why my previous button doesn't contain parameter for the controller ? PagedList MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pagedlist

i have a problem when implementing pagedlist mvc in my website project. I used pagedlist mvc to show partial view. When button previous is click, the parameter doesn't complete pass, just the page number that pass and the other is null. This is my controller

```
 public ActionResult StoreItemView(string jenis, string sorting_key, int? Page_No)
```

for **previous button** it will create link like this

```
localhost:20208/StoreItem/StoreItemView?Page_No=1
```

and has different with **next button**,that create link that contain all parameter

```
localhost:20208/StoreItem/StoreItemView?jenis=&sorting_key=&Page_No=2
```

why it's different call for previous and next button ?

i create the pager like this in cshtml

```
<div id="myPager">
    @Html.PagedListPager(
        Model,
        page => Url.Action(
            "StoreItemView",
            new
            {
                jenis = ViewBag.jenis,
                sorting_key = ViewBag.sorting_key,
                Page_No = page
            }
        ),
                PagedListRenderOptions.PageNumbersOnly
    )
</div>
```

and i use javascript too for load partial view , my javascript is

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#myPager').on('click', 'a', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#container_item_store').html(result);
                    alert("sukses");
                },
                error: alert("bangsat")
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

I stuck in this problem almost 2 days. I hope the people who are here can help me. Thank you before :)

**----EDIT------**

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<MVC_EDOLPUZ.Models.StoreItemModel>
@using System.Globalization
@using PagedList.Mvc
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<h3><span class="label label-primary">DOLANAN PUZZLE ITEM</span></h3>
<select id="Sorting_Order" name="Sorting" onchange="reloadPartialDDL()">
    <option value="0">-Urutkan Berdasarkan-</option>
    <option value="nama">Nama</option>
    <option value="rendah">Harga Terendah</option>
    <option value="tinggi">Harga Tertinggi</option>
</select>

<div id="products" class="row list-group">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="item  col-xs-5 col-lg-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="group list-group-image img-responsive" src="@Url.Content(@item.gambar_barang)" alt="" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                        @item.nama_barang
                    </h4>
                    <p class="group inner list-group-item-text">
                        <span class="label label-warning">@item.deksripsi_barang</span> 
                    </p>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-6">
                            <input id="@item.nama_barang" type="number" class="rating" min="1" max="5" step="0.5" data-size="xs" value="@item.rating_barang">
                        </div>
                        <script>
                            $('#@item.nama_barang').rating('refresh', { disabled: true, showClear: false, showCaption: false });
                        </script>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-5 col-xs-4">
                            <p class="lead" style="font-weight: bolder; color: red;">
                                @string.Format(new CultureInfo("id-ID"), "{0:C}", @item.harga_barang)
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-2">
                            <a class="btn btn-success btn-responsive btn-xs" onclick="addItemToCart('@item.id_barang')" href="#">Add to cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@*@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
    new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))*@

<div id="myPager">
    @Html.PagedListPager(
        Model,
        page => Url.Action(
            "StoreItemView",
            new
            {
                jenis = ViewBag.jenis,
                sorting_key = ViewBag.sorting_key,
                Page_No = page
            }
        ),
                PagedListRenderOptions.PageNumbersOnly
    )
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#myPager').on('click', 'a', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#container_item_store').html(result);
                    alert("sukses");
                },
                error: alert("bangsat")
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

that's my code for the view, and this **controller** that handle it's view

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult StoreItemView(string jenis, string sorting_key, int? Page_No)
{

    ViewBag.jenis = jenis;
    ViewBag.sorting_key = sorting_key;
    List<StoreItemModel> products = StoreItemRepository.getItemList(jenis, sorting_key);
    foreach (var items in products)
    {
        items.rating_barang = StoreItemRepository.getRatingBarang(items.id_barang);
    }
    int Size_Of_Page = 4;
    int No_Of_Page = (Page_No ?? 1);
    PagedList.PagedList<StoreItemModel> show = new PagedList.PagedList<StoreItemModel>(products, No_Of_Page, Size_Of_Page);
    return PartialView("_StoreItem", show);
}
```

Comment: Are parameter jenis and sorting_key is null or empty?

Comment: @JeffreyZhang for first it show, it contain string.empty. Because the parameter for sorting order.

Comment: I can bale to help you if you put your view code that contains the link tag. Please give those it will help us to lead you in correct way.

Comment: Are you their? hello

Comment: @Aravindan, sorry for late to reply, i have edit my question. You can see it now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use like below

```
<div id="myPager" location="Url.Action("StoreItemView", new {jenis = ViewBag.jenis, sorting_key = ViewBag.sorting_key, Page_No = page})">

@Html.PagedListPager(
    Model,
    page => Url.Action("StoreItemView"),
    PagedListRenderOptions.PageNumbersOnly
)
```

and javascript must be like 
 Before using the please check  **ViewBag.sorting_key** and **ViewBag.jenis**  is holding any value using alert in javascript. and I am not qable to  see any tag with id="container_item_store". Make sure the **container_item_store** id must be place in some where in your view.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#myPager').on('click', 'a', function () {
     var location = $(this).attr('location');
        $.ajax({
            url: location,
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#container_item_store').html(result);
                alert("sukses");
            },
            error: alert("bangsat")
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```